# SessionHelper class storing the last user only

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, session-variables

We have this helper class for accessing sessions, but it only stores the last value. I am unable to detect any bugs.

```
public interface ISessionHelper
{
    void AddToSession<T>(string key, T value);
    T GetFromSession<T>(string key);
    void RemoveFromSession(string key);
}

public class SessionHelper : ISessionHelper
{
    private static SessionHelper sessionHelper;
    private Dictionary<string, object> sessionCollection;
    private const string SESSION_MASTER_KEY = "SESSION_MASTER";

    private SessionHelper()
    {
        if (null == sessionCollection)
        {
            sessionCollection = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
    }

    public static ISessionHelper Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == sessionHelper)
            {
                sessionHelper = new SessionHelper();
            }
            return sessionHelper;
        }
    }

    public void AddToSession<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        sessionCollection[key] = value;
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(SESSION_MASTER_KEY, sessionCollection);
    }

    public void RemoveFromSession(string key)
    {
        sessionCollection.Remove(key);
    }

    public T GetFromSession<T>(string key)
    {
        var sessionCollection = HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_MASTER_KEY] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        if (null != sessionCollection)
        {
            if (sessionCollection.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return (T)sessionCollection[key];
            }
            else
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Session Abandoned");
        }
    }
}
```

The calls to this class are done as follows:

```
SessionHelper.Instance.AddToSession(SessionConstants.CURRENT_USER_INFO, user);
```

I think that initializing the dictionary part of the class is causing issues, but am unable to pinpoint it.

Or could this be the problem?

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CUserRoles userRoles;

    string currentUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

    User user = UserManager.GetUserCompleteInfo(currentUser, out userRoles);

    if (user != null && user.UserID > 0)
    {
        SessionHelper.Instance.AddToSession(SessionConstants.CURRENT_USER_INFO, user);

        if (userRoles != null)
        {
            SessionHelper.Instance.AddToSession(SessionConstants.CURRENT_USER_ROLE, userRoles);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that since the `sessionCollection` is a member of a singleton, that has a role. I would just remove the member `sessionCollection` pull that out of the session and use that or insert it as needed in each method. Your `GetFromSession` looks like the right pattern.

A simpler way would be to do this. Call this to get your collection.

```
private Dictionary<string, object> GetSessionCollection() 
{ 
     // add locking
    var collection = HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_MASTER_KEY] as Dictionary<string, object>;

    if (collection == null) 
    {
        collection = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_MASTER_KEY] = collection;
    }

    return collection;
}
```

An updated `AddToSession`

```
public void AddToSession<T>(string key, T value)
{
    var sessionCollection = GetSessionCollection();
    sessionCollection.Add(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet. I'm not getting what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Charlie i have posted one.

Comment: But wouldn't that lead to a change in the AddToSession() method?

Comment: @Charlie i would change all of them.

Comment: Not asking for a down vote, but may I request you to update your code with the AddToSession()